# Levantar ventana modal al hacer clic en DataTable

Tags: datatable

O al menos que se ejecute un `Alert`.

He intentado de varias formas pero no consigo que se muestre un mensaje al darle clic a un registro, no quiero usar un boton pues quita espacio.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tProd').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
        {"targets": [ 0 ], "visible": false},
        {"targets": [ 5 ], "visible": false}],
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"} );

    var table = $('#tProd').DataTable();    
        $('#tProd tbody').on( "click", "td", function (e) {
            var rowIdx = table.row( this ).index();
            var sData = table.cells({ row: rowIdx, column: 1 }).data()[1];
            if (sData && sData.length) {
            //location.href = 'modal.php'
          alert("I am an alert box!");
            }
        });      
    } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row fondo">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">CONSULTA DE STOCK</h1>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="cuadro1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                <h3 class="text-center"> <small class="mensaje"></small></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive col-sm-12">       
                        <table id="tProd" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>                               
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ID SIST</th>
                <th>CODIGO</th>
                <th>PRODUCTO</th>
                <th>STOCK</th>
                <th>FECHA</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>   
        <tbody>
            <?php $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user", "pass", "bd");
            $consulta = "SELECT ID, MEM_ID, LPAD(MPR_ID,5,'0') MPR_ID, CODIGO, NOMBRE, TOT, TIEMPO FROM MPR";
            if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)){while($obj = $resultado -> fetch_object())
            { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php printf($obj->ID);?></td>
                <td><?php printf($obj->MPR_ID);?></td>
                <td><?php printf($obj->CODIGO);?></td>
                <td><?php printf($obj->NOMBRE);?></td>
                <td><?php printf($obj->TOT);?></td>
                <td><?php printf($obj->TIEMPO);?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }
            $resultado->close();
            } ?>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       </div>          
     </div>    
   </div>
</body>
```

También pueden encontrr mi código en https://pastebin.com/SVga0V66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas rápido que puedes hacer es meter este código en los `tr`

```
<tr id = "<?=$obj->ID?>" onclick="console.log(this.id);">
     <td><?php printf($obj->ID);?></td>
     <td><?php printf($obj->MPR_ID);?></td>
     <td><?php printf($obj->CODIGO);?></td>
     <td><?php printf($obj->NOMBRE);?></td>
     <td><?php printf($obj->TOT);?></td>
     <td><?php printf($obj->TIEMPO);?></td>
</tr>
```

En el evento onclick fácilmente puedes mandar a llamar a tu modal por ejemplo que le pases una función con el parámetro del id

```
 <tr id = "<?=$obj->ID?>" onclick="mostrar_modal(this.id);">
```

tu función de script

```
  function mostrar_modal(id){
       console.log(id);
      $('#mi_modal').modal("show");
    }
```

Comment: Estimado @huichochitlan muchas gracias por la respuesta como se aprecia en esta imagen: i.snipboard.io/OQdv3r.jpg Pero si en la funcion pongo: function mostrar_modal(id){ //$('#edit').modal("show");} y mas abajo tengo ese codigo: i.snipboard.io/I6pnEa.jpg No levanta el modal. Ya llego al registro pero no levanta el modal

Comment: Puede ser que no tengas jQuery en los scripts

Answer (score -1):

Siguiendo este enlace del propio sitio de Datatables puede estar la solución:

[Events: Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/events.html)

Hay se puede ver el elemnto select, que ademas de pintar la linea a la que le diste click, tambien genera eventos.